# Sockets: Dealing with an example from APUE book

Tags: c, sockets

Consider the following example from APUE book:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
int initserver(int type, const struct sockaddr *addr, 
                    socklen_t alen, int qlen)
{
    int fd;
    int err = 0;
    if ((fd = socket(addr->sa_family, type, 0)) < 0)
        return -1;
    if (bind(fd, addr, alen) < 0) {
        err = errno;
        goto errout;
    }
    if (type == SOCK_STREAM || type == SOCK_SEQPACKET) {
        if (listen(fd, qlen) < 0) {
            err = errno;
            goto errout;
        }
    }
    return(fd);
errout:
    close(fd);
    errno = err;
    return -1;
}
```

The question is why `errno` is saved and then restored? Because it can be set in `close(fd)`? Why it can be ignored then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's (probably) because of the `close` call. The return from the `close` and it's possible error is ignored because the caller of `initserver` most likely want the error from the `socket` or `listen` function if one of them fail, not from the `close` function which can set `errno` to something completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: The question is why errno is saved and then restored? Because it
>   can be set in close(fd)?

A: Yes - exactly.

I *revere* Stevens ... but frankly, I wouldn't do this.  If I want to preserve the original errno, I'd save it to - then read it from - my own variable.

IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

errno hold the last error encountred.

close(fd) can cause an error and overwrite the value of errno, he restore it later because the caller function  might execute perror which print the value of errno,so the relevant error will be printed